# Adjusting a UITableView's Size in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4

I'm new to iPhone programming, and started to use Xcode 4. It seems like there is not much documentation over the internet for Xcode 4, and most of it is for older versions. I created a TableView using a TableView controller, but It's the size of the screen, and I want it to be smaller. Can I either change the size of the TableView in the TableView controller's settings, or drag a TableView object to my ViewController and connect it somehow to a Controller?
thanks

Comment: @dasdom: I think starting the post with "I'm new to iPhone programming" makes it pretty clear but I'll add the tag for him.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to shrink the UITableView so you can put other views above or below it. If that's the case, it may be easier for you to create a new UIViewController subclass with a XIB instead of a UITableViewController. Once in Interface Builder editing the XIB, drag a UITableView into the view controller's view, size the tableview the way you want, drag in the other subviews you want, then make IBOutlets in the UIViewController subclass's header file for the views you need to access in your code.

Apple is the best source that I know of for XCode 4 information. Maybe start at http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html. If you have a developer account, you can view the 2011 WWDC videos for free: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/. There are some good sessions on XCode 4 in the Developer Tools technology track.